Strange behavior of global go variable in c-archive compiled library
everyone.
Right now I'm writing my "scientific work" about fuzzing and I've got a problem with something in my fuzzing lib.
I try to fuzz go-ethereum lib (specificly bn256 part of it):
go-ethereum
My fuzzer uses DynamoRIO and libfuzzer code base, so I tryed to compile Golang lib to static library and fuzz some functions from there. But there are some troubles with compiling go-functions to C-lib. And the biggest one is pointers.
I used this article as an example: tutorial
I wrote handlers and handler collector (ObjectCollector=OC) in Go to handle pointers and tryed to use only indices of poiters in OC. And it kinda works BUT all changes in global OC object don't save. And I don't know why!
On this screen you can see that after every New operation OC.handlers is empty regurdless it is not when New function is running!
work logs
I don't know Golang well - in fact I can just read it and write some basic constructions.
My repo with all code, scripts and etc. is here: my_repo
Go main file code, where I prepare lib code to be exported.
// Copyright 2018 Péter Szilágyi. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be found
// in the LICENSE file.

//go:build amd64 || arm64
// +build amd64 arm64

// Package bn256 implements the Optimal Ate pairing over a 256-bit Barreto-Naehrig curve.
package main

import "C"
import (
    bn256cf "bn/cloudflare" // "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/bn256/cloudflare"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

// G1 is an abstract cyclic group. The zero value is suitable for use as the
// output of an operation, but cannot be used as an input.
type G1 = bn256cf.G1

// G2 is an abstract cyclic group. The zero value is suitable for use as the
// output of an operation, but cannot be used as an input.
type G2 = bn256cf.G2

// PairingCheck calculates the Optimal Ate pairing for a set of points.
//
//export PairingCheck
func PairingCheck(a []*G1, b []*G2) bool {
    return bn256cf.PairingCheck(a, b)
}

type Handler interface {
    Create()
    Close()
}

type ObjCollection struct {
    handlers []Handler
}

func (oc ObjCollection) CloseAll() {
    for i := 0; i < len(oc.handlers); i++ {
        oc.handlers[i].Close()
    }
    oc.handlers = make([]Handler, 0)
}

func (oc ObjCollection) GetHandler(id int) (handler Handler) {
    return oc.handlers[id]
}

func (oc ObjCollection) AddHandler(h Handler) (id int) {
    oc.handlers = append(oc.handlers, h)
    fmt.Println("handlers: ", oc.handlers)
    return len(oc.handlers) - 1
}

type Handler_G1 struct{ Val *G1 }
type Handler_G2 struct{ Val *G2 }
type Handler_bigInt struct{ Val *big.Int }

func (h Handler_G1) Create()     { h.Val = new(G1) }
func (h Handler_G2) Create()     { h.Val = new(G2) }
func (h Handler_bigInt) Create() { h.Val = new(big.Int) }

func (h Handler_G1) Close()     { h.Val = nil }
func (h Handler_G2) Close()     { h.Val = nil }
func (h Handler_bigInt) Close() { h.Val = nil }

func (h Handler_G1) Get() *G1             { return h.Val }
func (h Handler_G2) Get() *G2             { return h.Val }
func (h Handler_bigInt) Get() interface{} { return h.Val }

func (h Handler_G1) Set(g1 *G1)             { h.Val = g1 }
func (h Handler_G2) Set(g2 *G2)             { h.Val = g2 }
func (h Handler_bigInt) Set(bi interface{}) { h.Val = bi.(*big.Int) }

var OC ObjCollection

//export PrintOC
func PrintOC() {
    fmt.Println("OC: ", OC)
}

//export New_G1
func New_G1(k int) int {
    fmt.Println("===============")
    fmt.Println("     NEW G1")
    fmt.Println("===============")
    K := (&big.Int{}).SetInt64(int64(k))
    g1 := new(G1).ScalarBaseMult(K)
    fmt.Println("g1: ", g1)
    fmt.Println("K: ", K)
    var h Handler_G1
    h.Val = g1 // .Set(g1)
    fmt.Println("h: ", h)
    K = nil
    ind := OC.AddHandler(Handler(h))
    fmt.Println("===============")
    return ind
    // return 1
}

//export New_G2
func New_G2(k int) int {
    g2 := new(G2)
    K := new(big.Int).SetInt64(int64(k))
    var h Handler_G2
    h.Set(g2.ScalarBaseMult(K))
    K = nil
    ind := OC.AddHandler(h)
    return ind
}

//export ClearAll
func ClearAll() {
    OC.CloseAll()
}

//export Add_G1
func Add_G1(e_ind, i, j int) int {
    p1 := OC.GetHandler(i).(Handler_G1).Get()
    p2 := OC.GetHandler(j).(Handler_G1).Get()

    var e *G1
    if e_ind == -1 {
        e = &bn256cf.G1{}
        var h Handler_G1
        h.Set(e)
        e_ind = OC.AddHandler(h)
    } else {
        e = OC.GetHandler(e_ind).(Handler_G1).Get()
    }

    e.Add(p1, p2)
    return e_ind
}

func main() {}


And if we just left sindle array of handlers (do not wrap it into structure with methods) everything is fine!
I hate this magic :}

Your method receivers are copying the ObjCollection value. You need to use pointers.

Ok. Thanks. It's a really strange way to realize work with objects as for me))
